# Efficiently find centroid of labelled image regions

Tags: numpy, image-processing, gpu, image-segmentation, pytorch

I have a segmented image as a 2 dimensional matrix of unique labels 1 ... k. For example:

```
img = 
    [1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]
    [1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3]
    [1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
    [1 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 3]
    [4 4 4 5 5 5 2 3 3]
    [4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6]
    [4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6]
```

I am trying to determine the region centroids. That is, per label, what is the X,Y coordinate of the center of mass? For example, the centroid of label 1 is (1.25, 0.625). Just average up the row numbers (`(0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3) / 8 = 1.25`) and the column numbers (`(0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2) / 8 = 0.625`)

The only way I know how to do this is to use a for loop from 1 to k (or in the case of my example, 1 through 6), find the indices of the points for each label, and average their coordinates by indexing a meshgrid of the image.

However, I am looking to do this in a way optimized for GPU computations. Hence, the use of a for loop is less than ideal (takes about 1 sec per image on a nice GPU for a few hundred labels). I am using PyTorch, but really any numpy solution should suffice.

Is there a GPU-efficient solution for this task?

Answer (score 2):

This computation requires accumulation, I don't know how efficient that is on a GPU. This is the sequential algorithm in psuedo-code:

```
int n[k] = 0
int sx[k] = 0
int sy[k] = 0
loop over y:
   loop over x:
      i = img[x,y]
      ++n[i]
      sx[i] += x
      sy[i] += y
for i = 1 to k
    sx[i] /= n[i]
    sy[i] /= n[i]
```

And then of course, `(sx[i],sy[i])` is the centroid of object `i`.

It's really fast on a CPU, it's not worth the effort to send the data to the GPU for this, unless it's already there.

Comment: Yeah this is the best solution I could come up with too. The data is already on the GPU, hence why I thought to do it there :-/. I'll see how the CPU goes. This is certainly as efficient as it gets--every pixel touched once, but I'm wondering if there's a way to parallelize this on the GPU...

Comment: One thing you could do, if the naive GPU implementation of the algorithm above is too slow, is to create arrays `n`, `sx` and `sy` for each image column, then add them together later. That might reduce the number of cores waiting to do an atomic update of array values.

Comment: I'm not sure, is it efficient to update a single value in a global array atomically? Do you get false sharing problems on a GPU?

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to use [`bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to accumulate the row and column indices for each region using the numbers in the input array as the bins and thus have a vectorized solution, like so -

```
m,n = a.shape
r,c = np.mgrid[:m,:n]
count = np.bincount(a.ravel())
centroid_row = np.bincount(a.ravel(),r.ravel())/count
centroid_col = np.bincount(a.ravel(),c.ravel())/count
```

Sample run -

```
In [77]: a
Out[77]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])

In [78]: np.c_[centroid_row, centroid_col]
Out[78]: 
array([[  nan,   nan], 
       [ 1.25,  0.62], # centroid for region-1
       [ 1.56,  4.44], # centroid for region-2
       [ 1.9 ,  7.4 ], # centroid for region-3 and so on.
       [ 4.36,  1.18],
       [ 5.11,  3.67],
       [ 5.43,  6.71]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider either using [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) or reusing their [code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image) (based on numpy/scipy).

Here is a demo:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure
from time import perf_counter as pc

img = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                [1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3],
                [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6],
                [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]])

# assuming already labels of 1, 2, ... n
times = [pc()]
props = measure.regionprops(img)
times.append(pc())
for i in range(np.unique(img).shape[0]):
    print(props[i].centroid)
    times.append(pc())

print(np.diff(times))
```

Output:

```
(1.25, 0.625)
(1.5555555555555556, 4.4444444444444446)
(1.8999999999999999, 7.4000000000000004)
(4.3636363636363633, 1.1818181818181819)
(5.1111111111111107, 3.6666666666666665)
(5.4285714285714288, 6.7142857142857144)
[  9.05569615e-05   8.51235438e-04   2.48126075e-04   2.59294767e-04
   2.42692657e-04   2.00734598e-04   2.34542530e-04]
```